# Passing a templated functor as an argument to a templated function in C++

Tags: c++, templates, functor

I am trying to pass a templated functor into a templated function.
The code looks something like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
T func_1(T &a) {
    return a;
}

template <typename T>
T test(T &a, std::function<T(T&)> &func){
    return func(a);
}

int main(){
    int a = 5;
    std::cout << test(a, func_1) << std::endl;
}
```

However, I get the following compile error:

> invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::function<int(int&)>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘’

The code works if I remove the template. Can someone help me understand why?

Answer (score 2):

`func_1` is function template. You have to pass a concrete type you want this function to be instantiated. In your case it is `int`, type of `a` variable.

```
std::cout << test(a, func_1<decltype(a)>) << std::endl;
```

Then, `function` object can be created taking `func_1<int>` instantiation. This function is temporary, but temporary cannot be bound to *Lvalue* reference, so signature of `test` should be modified to accept const *Lvalue* ref:

```
template <typename T>
T test(T &a, const std::function<T(T&)> &func){
             // <---- const 
    return func(a);
}
```

Comment: This is magic! Thank you for explaining this so nicely.

Comment: @YashBansod accept the answer as complete then.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `func_1` is *just* a template, to get a function pointer you first need a function (ie an instantiation of the function template).

You can get what you want by making `func_1` an actual functor (ie callable object) that is not a template itself:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct func_1 {
    template <typename T>
    T operator()(T& a){ return a; }
};

template <typename T,typename F>
T test(T &a, F func){
    return func(a);
}

int main(){
    int a = 5;
    std::cout << test(a, func_1{}) << std::endl;
                         //    ^^ create instance
}
```

The "trick" is that only `func_1::operator()` is a template, so you can create objects of `func_1` and pass them around before you know what `T` actually is. The operator is only instantiated when it is called in `test` but not in `main`.

Comment: This is a nice alternative to @rafix07 's solution. Personally I preferred using his approach than this.

Comment: @YashBansod I'd definitely prefer rafix's solution too. I just didnt see the obvious.